# Assign more than 100 contributions to a Batch

Tags: civicontribute, batches

Is it possible to assign more than 100 contributions to a batch? We have a site with thousands of contributions so we want to make this job quicker. By default, you can only assign 10, 25, 50, 100 contributions to a batch.

Screenshot from
/civicrm/batchtransaction?reset=1&bid=x
[image: screenshot of accounting batch page]

Answer (score 1):

You add more than 100 transactions to a batch, but only up to 100 at a time.  I had to do this when first implementing the batch processing - creating a batch of previous transactions.

I just wish that Civi would remember the number of entries selected when returning from applying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

You can only select a maximum of 100, when you want to do a batch update. So I think the same restrictions would apply universally on batches.

Comment: You could however achieve the same thing, by running SQL-queries directly on the database. But use caution...!